# Send two different kinds of sensor data using Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-ide

I'm trying to config an Arduino with a PIR motion detector, to send motion detector data and some randomly generated temperature to the gateway.

I want to make it send "MO/1" once motion is detected and still keep sending temperature every 20 seconds like "T/26".

I've used this code but no success:

```
void loop() {
    if (motion == HIGH) {
       // Motion Detected
       // Send to Gateway
    }

    while (1) {
       temp = random(1,5) + 28;
       // Send to Gateway
       delay(20000);
    }
}
```

As you may notice, once Arduino enters `while` it won't pay attention to the `if` block! Since I'm new to Arduino and programming them, I thought someone could help with this.

Comment: As far as I understand it, the `loop` function will be continuously called over and over again. You don't need a loop inside it. If you need something to happen every 20 seconds then you should use some other way to check the time elapsed between the calls and check if at least 20 seconds has passed.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I know how to do it in JS but not in C++. I understand but I also Appreciate if you could tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't work as you noticed.

You need to use a variable, to calculate the time elapsed since last check.

```
unsigned long t1;
void setup() {
  ...
  t1=millis();
}

void loop() {
  if (motion == HIGH) {
     // Motion Detected
     // Send to Gateway
  }
  if(millis()-t1>20000) {
    temp = random(1, 5) + 28;
    // Send to Gateway
    t1=millis();
  }
}
```